# RxJava + Retrofit -> BaseObservable for API calls for centralized response handling

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am new to RxJava so please forgive me if this sounds too newbie :-).

As of now I have an abstract CallbackClass that implements the Retofit Callback. There I catch the Callback's "onResponse" and "onError" methods and handle various error types before finally forwarding to the custom implemented methods.
I also use this centralized class to for request/response app logging and other stuff.

For example: for specific error codes from my sever I receive a new Auth token in the response body, refresh the token and then clone.enqueue the call.
There are of course several other global behaviors to the responses from my server.

Current solution (Without Rx):

```
    public abstract void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response, boolean isSuccess);

    public abstract void onFailure(Call<T> call, Response<T> response, Throwable t, boolean isTimeout);

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (_isCanceled) return;

        if (response != null && !response.isSuccessful()) {
            if (response.code() == "SomeCode" && retryCount < RETRY_LIMIT) {
                TokenResponseModel newToken = null;
                try {
                    newToken = new Gson().fromJson(new String(response.errorBody().bytes(), "UTF-8"), TokenResponseModel.class);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    SomeClass.token = newToken.token;
                    retryCount++;
                    call.clone().enqueue(this);
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            onResponse(call, response, true);
            removeFinishedRequest();
            return;
        }

        onFailure(call, response, null, false);
        removeFinishedRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        if (_isCanceled) return;

        if (t instanceof UnknownHostException)
            if (eventBus != null)
                eventBus.post(new NoConnectionErrorEvent());

        onFailure(call, null, t, false);
        removeFinishedRequest();
    }
```

My question is: Is there any way to have this sort of centralized response handling behavior before finally chaining (or retrying) back to the subscriber methods?

I found these 2 links which both have a nice starting point but not a concrete solution. Any help will be really appreciated.

[Forcing request retry after custom API exceptions in RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919190/forcing-request-retry-after-custom-api-exceptions-in-rxjava?rq=1)

[Retrofit 2 and RxJava error handling operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740066/retrofit-2-and-rxjava-error-handling-operators)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two links you provided are a really good starting point, which I used to construct solution to react to accidental

- network errors happen sometimes due to temporary lack of network connection, or switch to low throughtput network standard, like EDGE, which causes SocketTimeoutException
- server errors  -> happen sometimes due to server overload

I have overriden `CallAdapter.Factory` to handle errors and react appropriately to them.

1. Import `RetryWithDelayIf` from the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33768184/6507689) you found
2. Override `CallAdapter.Factory` to handle errors:

   ```
   public class RxCallAdapterFactoryWithErrorHandling extends CallAdapter.Factory {
       private final RxJavaCallAdapterFactory original;

       public RxCallAdapterFactoryWithErrorHandling() {
           original = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create();
       }

       @Override
       public CallAdapter<?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
           return new RxCallAdapterWrapper(retrofit, original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit));
       }

       public class RxCallAdapterWrapper implements CallAdapter<Observable<?>> {
           private final Retrofit retrofit;
           private final CallAdapter<?> wrapped;

           public RxCallAdapterWrapper(Retrofit retrofit, CallAdapter<?> wrapped) {
               this.retrofit = retrofit;
               this.wrapped = wrapped;
           }

           @Override
           public Type responseType() {
               return wrapped.responseType();
           }

           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           @Override
           public <R> Observable<?> adapt(final Call<R> call) {
               return ((Observable) wrapped.adapt(call)).onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable>() {
                   @Override
                   public Observable call(Throwable throwable) {
                       Throwable returnThrowable = throwable;
                       if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                           HttpException httpException = (HttpException) throwable;
                           returnThrowable = httpException;
                           int responseCode = httpException.response().code();
                           if (NetworkUtils.isClientError(responseCode)) {
                               returnThrowable = new HttpClientException(throwable);
                           }
                           if (NetworkUtils.isServerError(responseCode)) {
                               returnThrowable = new HttpServerException(throwable);
                           }
                       }

                       if (throwable instanceof UnknownHostException) {
                           returnThrowable = throwable;
                       }

                       return Observable.error(returnThrowable);
                   }
               }).retryWhen(new RetryWithDelayIf(3, DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS, new Func1<Throwable, Boolean>() {
                   @Override
                   public Boolean call(Throwable throwable) {
                       return throwable instanceof HttpServerException
                               || throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException
                               || throwable instanceof UnknownHostException;
                   }
               }));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   `HttpServerException` is just a custom exception.
3. Use it in [`Retrofit.Builder`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html)

   ```
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .addCallAdapterFactory(new RxCallAdapterFactoryWithErrorHandling())
           .build();
   ```

**Extra**: If you wish to parse errors that come from API (error that don't invoke `UnknownHostException`, `HttpException` or `MalformedJsonException` or etc.) you need to override [`Factory`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Converter.Factory.html) and use custom one during building `Retrofit` instance. Parse the response and check if it contains errors. If yes, then throw error and error will be handled inside the method above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to implement this code and let you know before I can accept the answer. Just a question... With your solution what is your return type? a Observable<Result<ResObject>>, Observable<Response<ResObject>> or just a plain Observable<ResObject>. Elaborating a bit more on your "extra" could be nice as well (-;

Comment: The type of `Observable` stays the same with or without the code. It is just delaying the response if request is repeated, or throws a more specific error, than the default Retrofit error: `HttpException`.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet of handling Api errors that dont invoke UnknownHostException as you have mentioned in your "extra"? Thanks in advance

Comment: will it be possible to make the solution compatible with rxjava2 and the newly released retrofit rxjava2 call adapter?

Answer (score 0):

have you consider using the rxjava adapter for retrofit? 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava/2.1.0
in your gradle file add

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

here's a interface for retrofit

```
public interface Service {
@GET("userauth/login?")
Observable<LoginResponse> getLogin(
        @Query("v") String version,
        @Query("username") String username,
        @Query("password") String password);
}
```

and here's my implementation

```
Service.getLogin(
            VERSION,
            "username",
            "password")
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(LoginResponse loginResponse) {

                }
            });
```

please note I'm using the gson converter factory to parse my response so I get an pojo (Plain Ole Java Object) returned.

Comment: Well of course I am talking about using the RxJava adapter. Your sample is the very basic use of Retrofit + Rx. The question was how to get the pattern used in my example when not using Rx, for generic and centralized error handling while using the RxCallAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

See how you can do it.
 Here is api call and pass Request model and response model in this.

```
public interface RestService {
//SEARCH_USER
@POST(SEARCH_USER_API_LINK)
Observable<SearchUserResponse> getSearchUser(@Body SearchUserRequest getSearchUserRequest);
}
```

This is the retrofit call,I used retrofit2

```
public RestService getRestService() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(getOkHttpClient())
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(RestService.class);
}

//get OkHttp instance
@Singleton
@Provides
public OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.interceptors().add(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    builder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return builder.build();
}
```

This is the api call, call it in your activity.

```
@Inject
Scheduler mMainThread;
@Inject
Scheduler mNewThread;

 //getSearchUser api method
public void getSearchUser(String user_id, String username) {

    SearchUserRequest searchUserRequest = new SearchUserRequest(user_id, username);

    mObjectRestService.getSearchUser(searchUserRequest).
            subscribeOn(mNewThread).
            observeOn(mMainThread).
            subscribe(searchUserResponse -> {
                Timber.e("searchUserResponse :" + searchUserResponse.getResponse().getResult());
                if (isViewAttached()) {
                    getMvpView().hideProgress();
                    if (searchUserResponse.getResponse().getResult() == ApiConstants.STATUS_SUCCESS) {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                if (isViewAttached()) {

                }
            });
}
```

Hope this will help you.